# Routing works fine in local storage but it doesn't on GitHub Pages

Tags: angular-cli, github-pages

I am trying to make a web site that is this one: https://username.github.io/page-name/. If you navigate inside the site, everything works perfectly. The problem is that I would want to share an specific link, which is https://username.github.io/page-name/agendar, but it redirects to the 404 page instead of redirect to the "agenda" page.

To generate my site, used the following command:
`ng build --output-path docs --base-href /page-name/`

My Angular version is:

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.5
Node: 18.15.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 15.2.6
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.5
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.5
@angular/cli                    15.2.5
@schematics/angular             15.2.5
rxjs                            7.8.0
typescript                      4.9.5
```

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles - use the hash style, GitHub Pages doesn't support push-state routing without some hacking.